# Merge associations with those from duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Say I have a resource named Product. Each product `has_many :images`.

Users are allowed to create new products, and after a while I notice that there's a bunch of Products that seem to be the same.

So I add this to the Product model:

```
belongs_to :duplicate_of, class_name: 'Product'
has_many :duplicates, class_name: 'Product'
```

I then add a "Mark as duplicate" method which will assign the `duplicate_of` association. I then make any request to a product which has a duplicate_of redirect to that product instead.

Now, for the "real" product I want to show **all** images, even those assigned to the duplicates. I don't want to reassociate the images since I want to be able to undo the "Mark as duplicate" action.

So I need something like `self_or_through` for `has_many`. Does something like this exists or should I just overload `images` and do the work myself?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you storing duplicate product information. You can use custom :finder_sql

Comment: I think this question here is why do you have duplicate products?

Comment: Well 'product' was just an example. The resources are created by users and so of course there will be duplicates (just like questions on SO).

Comment: How do you mean 'storing duplicate product inforamtion'?